# Circle: finding locus of the chord's mid point

Tags: vectors, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, locus

Find the locus of the middle points of chords of the circle $$x^2+y^2 =a^2$$ which subtends a right angle at the point $(c, 0)$

Comment: Can you show some attempt?

Comment: We can find the equation of the two lines passing through C, 0 and the circle

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371647/finding-the-locus-of-the-midpoint-of-chord-that-subtends-a-right-angle-at-alp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Let $\Gamma$ be a circle centered at $O$ with radius $R$ and $P$ a point inside $\Gamma$. Let $ABCD$ a quadrilateral inscribed in $\Gamma$ with orthogonal diagonals $AC,BD$ meeting at $P$. By Thales' theorem the midpoints of $AB,BC,CD,DA$ are the vertices of a rectangle with sides parallel to $AC,BD$. Since $O$ is the circumcenter of $ABCD$, the lines joining $O$ with the previous midpoints are orthogonal to the sides of $ABCD$. By angle chasing those midpoints lie on a circle centered at the midpoint of $OP$, whose diameter equals $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{BD^2+AC^2}$. Let $u,v$ be the distances of $O$ from $AC,BD$. By the Pythagorean theorem we have $u^2+v^2=OP^2$ and $\left(\frac{1}{2}AC\right)^2+u^2 = OA^2 = R^2$, hence 
$$\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{AC^2+BD^2}=\sqrt{2R^2-OP^2}$$
is constant and the midpoints of $AB,BC,CD,DA$ lie on a fixed **circle** centered at the midpoint of $OP$. This essentially is the [Proposition $11$ from Archimedes' Book of Lemmas](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/BookOfLemmas/BOL11.shtml), which is used to prove the [pizza theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pizza_theorem), too (if you are confident with Italian, you may have a look at page 21 of [these notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwSWVCckk1cll3ZGM/view), too).

Comment: I've to study this solution! How did you plot the figure, very nice!

Comment: @gimusi: Geogebra does wonderful things.

Comment: I've to try it, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Say $AB$ is a chord and $R$ it's midpoint. Say $P= (c,0)$ and $S=
(0,0)$ and $T$ the midpoint of $SP$. Then I claim, that $R$
describe a circle with center in $T$. We use a position vectors to
prove it.

Since $\angle APB = 90^{\circ}$ we have $\overrightarrow{PA}\cdot
\overrightarrow{PB} =0$ so we have
$$(\overrightarrow{A}-\overrightarrow{P})\cdot (\overrightarrow{B}-\overrightarrow{P})= 0\;\;\;\;\Longrightarrow \;\;\;\; \overrightarrow{A}\cdot \overrightarrow{B} -\overrightarrow{P}\cdot (\overrightarrow{A}+\overrightarrow{B}) +\overrightarrow{P}^2 =0$$

Say $S$ is the origin, then $||\overrightarrow{A}|| =
||\overrightarrow{B}|| =r$ and $\overrightarrow{R} = {1\over
2}(\overrightarrow{A}+\overrightarrow{B})$ and
$\overrightarrow{T}={1\over
2}(\overrightarrow{S}+\overrightarrow{P}) = {1\over
2}\overrightarrow{P}$

\begin{eqnarray}
 ||\overrightarrow{RT}||^2 &=& \overrightarrow{RT}^2 = (\overrightarrow{T}-\overrightarrow{R})^2\\
&=& {1\over 4} (\overrightarrow{P}-\overrightarrow{A}-\overrightarrow{B})^2\\
&=& {1\over 4}(\overrightarrow{P}^2+\overrightarrow{A}^2+\overrightarrow{B}^2-2\overrightarrow{P}\cdot (\overrightarrow{A}+\overrightarrow{B})+2\overrightarrow{A}\cdot \overrightarrow{B})\\
&=& {1\over 4}(r^2+r^2-\overrightarrow{P}^2) =const.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: very nice solution!